Digital Ocean Expose API Schema (ie GraphQL Playground)
I’m running a DigitalOcean App as our team’s backend dev server so that the frontend team doesn’t need to keep pulling updates from the backend, but I need to expose the API schema (ie graphql playground). But I’m not sure how to do it. We can query the backend endpoints just fine but we are accustomed to navigating to the api endpoint URL to view the available Schema. Any help is appreciated. Here's a snippet from my spec file that shows the shop-api and admin-api endpoints that I'd like to show the Schema to:
ingress:
  rules:
  - component:
      name: frontend
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /
  - component:
      name: backend
      preserve_path_prefix: true
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /admin
  - component:
      name: backend
      preserve_path_prefix: true
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /admin-api
  - component:
      name: backend
      preserve_path_prefix: true
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /health
  - component:
      name: backend
      preserve_path_prefix: true
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /shop-api

